# Unity2D Enemy Patrol, weird sprite rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Needed help here, I've been following this tutorial about Enemy Patrolling, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKU3ejp0Alg

The tutorial tell us to set 2 Empty Game Objects and the coordinates so the sprite will walk from one direction to another, the walking does working, however the rotation of the sprite became really weird, the 'Worm' sprite is suppose to move left and right now it change into facing upward
Please look at this image,

When moving from left to right
[image]

When moving from right to left

[image]

```
public Transform[] patrolPoints;
public float speed;
Transform currentPatrolPoint;
int currentPatrolIndex;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    currentPatrolIndex = 0;
    currentPatrolPoint = patrolPoints[currentPatrolIndex];
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, currentPatrolPoint.position) < .1f) {
        if (currentPatrolIndex + 1 < patrolPoints.Length)
            currentPatrolIndex++;
        else
            currentPatrolIndex = 0;
        currentPatrolPoint = patrolPoints[currentPatrolIndex];
    }

    Vector3 patrolPointDir = currentPatrolPoint.position - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(patrolPointDir.y, patrolPointDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;

    Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, q, 180f);

}
```

This is the code

Thank you

Comment: Instead of rotate, set the local scale x value to -1 or minus what ever the positive is. Surprisingly this works.

Comment: @Catwood How to do that? change which code?
Thanks

Comment: swap the last 2 lines for `transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1,1);` to flip it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the optional parameter `Space.World` to your translation to move your object relative to world space instead of object space. That should prevent your object from rotating.

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed, Space.World);
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html).

Answer (score 0):

You probably rotated the enemy sprite by 90 degrees. Try placing all your scripts into empty game object with no rotation, than place the enemy sprite as child of the empty game object and rotate as you need. This way your logic won't collide with your graphics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't rotate the enemy sprite tho! It looks normal

Comment: It has rotation in inspector, I'm sure. You are moving it with `Vector3.up`, that moves by the Y axis, not the X axis that is left/right.

Comment: Is it possible to help me adjust the code and disable the rotation? The sprite has no rotation but I think the script does have

Comment: remove `- 90f` from `float angle = Mathf.Atan2(patrolPointDir.y, patrolPointDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;` and change to `Vector3.right` in translate code. The movement may be reversed, in that case multiply `Vectoe3.right` with -1